# Perl: how to validate successful call to "XML::eXistDB::RPC"

Tags: perl, rpc, exist-db

i am writing a small perl app using the eXist database, and i am wondering is:
how can i see that my call

```
my $eXist = XML::eXistDB::RPC->new( destination=>$eXist_db, repository=>$bank, user=>"admin", password=>"pass" ) ;
```

is successful or not ?

thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When object initialisation fails, it will be messaged through [Log::Report](http://p3rl.org/Log%3a%3aReport), so hook into that.

This only happens if the programmer to neglected to set either `rpc` or `destination` parameter. **The `new` constructor will always return an object instance**.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:

> All methods return a LIST, where the
>   first scalar is a return code (RC).
>   When that code is 0, all went well.
>   Otherwise, the code represent the
>   transport error or the exception
>   (refusal) as reported by the server
>   logic. In either case, the second
>   scalar in the returned list contains
>   the error message. For instance,

**Maybe** this applies also for the constructor, try:

```
my ($rc,$eXist) = XML::eXistDB::RPC->new( destination=>$eXist_db, repository=>$bank, user=>"admin", password=>"pass" );
```

now, if $rc != 0 there was an error.

Comment: thank you soulSurfer2010 for your interest, i tried that but unfortunately no luck. any other ideas ?

Comment: i have also tried : isa_ok($eXist, "XML::eXistDB::RPC") ; but no dice :(